# Sweetalert2 redirect on confirm

Tags: sweetalert2

When the user clicks the confirm button in SweetAlert2 I'd like to redirect the user to another page and keep the modal open to show that the redirect is in progress.

I've managed to achieve using by re-initialising the modal after it closes and toggling the loading state. Is there a nicer built-in way? It was possible in the old v1.

```js
var redirect = function () {
    return Swal.fire({
        type: 'warning',
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        allowOutsideClick: false,
        preConfirm: function () { 
           window.location.href = 'https://dapurlindawaty.com';
        }
    });
};

redirect().then(function (result) {
    if (result.value) {
        redirect();
        Swal.showLoading();
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bytestream/vfzgx10L/2/